# tar file with combination of directory name and original timestamp

Tags: python, shell, sh, tar

I want to create the tar file which contains the combination directory name and original timestamp. There are so many files which needs to convert in above format.

For the directory below, I expect the new tar file name would be `rs_jul_29_2016.tar`

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Jul 29  2016 rs
```

Comment: What did you try? Where does *Python* come into play?

Comment: @CristiFati, this is not a Python issue.  Python is one tool available for a solution, though you might call it overkill.

Comment: @tnknepp: this is your assumption. My point is that the question is not answerable in its current form (without further clarification from *OP*).

Comment: @CristiFati: correct.  I assumed I knew the OP's intention when I posted my answer.  However, my assumption may be wrong.  The OP should update this question to provide clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.stat()` to get the last modified time and `datetime` to convert that into the string timestamp that you want.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

filename = 'rs'
st = os.stat(filename)
modified_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)
tar_filename = modified_time.strftime('{}_%b_%m_%Y.tar'.format(filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have both Python and shell/sh flagged as keywords, so here goes for both.

## Python

```
import os
import tarfile

dst = '/destination/directory/path/'
src = '/source/directory/path/'

# list current date
heute = dt.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d_')

# assuming only have directories in current directory
for d in os.listdir(src):
    # define .tar destination filename
    dst_fn = dst + heute + d + '.tar'

    with tarfile.open(dst_fn, 'w') as fid:
        fid.add(d)
```

## bash

```
tmstamp=$(date '%Y%m%d')

cd directory

for dir in */
do
  base=$(basename "$dir")
  tar -cf "${tmstamp}_${base}.tar" "$dir"
done
```

Both of those should create a tar file for each directory of interest.  My recommendation: create a dummy directory and test each out before you do it for real just to make sure...